# How to update arangodb if I change the OS

Tags: ubuntu, arangodb

I installed arangodb on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, after that, I upgrade my ubuntu to 15.10 and soon will upgrade it to 16.04 LTS, what should I do to my arangodb? Should I re-install based on my Ubuntu version, or there is some workaround to do?

Thank you,
Elmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ArangoDB offers all releases across recent Ubuntu versions, (we need gcc 4.9 at least to build the releases) you should be able to update/upgrade ArangoDB at a different pace than your OS. Means:

- Follow the [ArangoDB Blog where we anounce releases](https://www.arangodb.com/blog/) including the changes and bugfixes.
- keep up with the latest released ArangoDB for your Ubuntu release
- Once a new Ubuntu is released, update the OS, and install the ArangoDB package for your new OS which should in term be the same release as you had before.

You should be able to achieve this by simply properly configuring your apt sources.list; You first download and add the Signature key to your packaging system:

```
wget https://www.arangodb.com/repositories/arangodb2/xUbuntu_14.10/Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key
```

Use apt-get to install arangodb:

```
echo 'deb https://www.arangodb.com/repositories/arangodb2/xUbuntu_14.10/ /' |\
    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arangodb.list
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arangodb=2.8.7
```

Once you do the upgrade to 15.10, you edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/arangodb.list` and change the ubuntu release to 15.10, and run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arangodb=2.8.7
```

to get the package for the new OS release.

Comment: What about my record in arangoDB from the previous Ubuntu version? Can I use it again?

Comment: unless you change the processor architecture you should be able to re-use your datafiles without problems. On upgrading ArangoDB to a new version you need to run it once with --upgrade.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation